# Android - calculating and storing the answer of an arithmetic expression

Tags: java, android, math, android-layout, arithmetic-expressions

What would be best way to get the answer to this question which is using random numbers and random operators.

```
  editTextEquation.setText(random1 +(String.valueOf(ops[i1]) + random2 +     (String.valueOf(ops[i2])+ random3 + (String.valueOf(ops[i3])+ random4))));
```

I'm displaying this question and then will check the answer against user input. I'm guessing I'd need to store the answer first. Any help/advice will be very much appreciated.

Here is how I am generating the expression:

```
 int random1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
 int random2 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
 int random3 = (int)(Math.random()*200);
 int random4 = (int)(Math.random()*20);

 int min = 0;
 int max = 3;
 Random r = new Random();
 int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min);
 int i2 = r.nextInt(max - min);
 int i3 = r.nextInt(max - min);

 char[] ops = { '+', '-', '/', '*' };

 int answer;
```

Comment: Looks like you store the operands as strings, have you considered storing them as `int/double`, that should shift some of the logic of getting the values away, and mean's you can just calculate the answer each time

Comment: Could you be more precise and give more examples

Comment: @dann.dev, how would I do that? just change char to int? and then tweak the setText code?

Comment: Sorry read the question wrong, check out my answer below, it's kind of a quick hack but it will get the job done

Answer (score 1):

How long do you need to hold on to the answer?

If it's only for a short time, a variable will be sufficient.

If you need it for a long time, consider creating a SQLite database to store it.  Generate an ID for your expression and store them both in the database.  Then you can look them up later at your leisure.

Comment: How would I go about calculating the answer using a variable?

Comment: Make an `Expression` class that encapsulates your expression string that your user is looking at and give is a `solution` member.  Then you've got the answer as long as you've also got the `Expression`.  As for calculating the answer, I suppose I assumed you already had that part sorted out since you seemed more interested in storing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have small problems, so only a couple of `+` and `-` etc, you could try creating a string to represent it, and an underlying operation to find the answer, for example

```
public int calculate(int operation, int a, int b, int c) {
    if (operation ==1) {
        //must be all plus
        return a+b+c;
    }else if (operation ==2)
        //another case
        return a+b-c;
    }else if ( etc etc

}

public void displayQuestion(int operation, int a, int b, int c) {
   if(operation ==1) {
      System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " + " + c + " =");
   }else if( etc etc
}
```

You could then display each question and request the answer depending on what it was. This is a simple way that will require you having every case specified. You can probably easily make it alot smarter, this is a quick simple way, to do it properly (parse the string as a math query) is a bit harder and I need to get back to my actual work!